# arduino flexbot drone connected in a wrong way

Tags: arduino-leonardo

I have an arduino [flexbot](http://www.flexbot.cc/), I was making some test and accidentally I connected the battery in the opposite way. The drone turned on the six motors when I connected the battery, but any led turned on to see if the processor was working. I disconnected the battery and connected it in the wrong way again same thing happened the six motors turned on again. Then I realize that the battery was connected in a wrong way and connected it in the right way. The LED's turned on as always, and also the blue-tooth module was working I could detect the device using the control-application. I tried to fly the drone but the motors didn't turn on, I could hear little click and I saw a little movement of a motor.

I connected my drone to my PC using the micro USB connection, also I connected the battery. I tried to turn on the drone and in this way it looks to work fine.

But when I disconnect the USB port and I tried to fly it the same thing happens, the click and the little movement. Any idea of what can I do to fix this drone?

Answer (score 2):

The motors turning on is expected because or the reverse diode in the mosfets driving the motor.

Looking at the schematic, it seems like the problem is on the 5v rail. If 5v isn't supplied by the USB port, it is provided by the LTC3200 (DC/DC converter)(U3 on the pcb). I think that's where the problem is, as that would explain why it only work when USB is connected.

To confirm this you'd have to measure the output voltage (pin1 (pin nearest to the ATMega) of U3, and see if it's 5 volt.

To fix it you should ideally replace this part. But it might also work without, if you simply connect the battery voltage directly to the 5v (i.e. jumper pins 1 and 5).

Comment: I measured the voltage of pin 1 in U3 without connect it to the USB port and the lecture was 3.0 V, and connected to the USB it was 4.5 V, Does that mean that I can connect the battery directly?

Comment: It should have been around 5 volt, not 3.0.  Though at 3v I'd have expected the MCU to work. But maybe they set a higher brownout-detection value. The battery is connected to pin 5 on the pcb. So connecting pins 1 and 5 is the most convenient way of connecting the battery voltage to the 5v rail.

Comment: I tried three things, the first one was connecting the battery directly to the pin 1, that  made the motors turn on for a second and then the click came back and motors turned off. The second one was remove the connection between battery and connect the pins 1 and 5, only can hear the click. And finally connect pin 1 and 5 to vcc, only three motors worked less than a second. Please feel free to post all the answers that you want, I'll give a like on each one. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to hear, that didn't work. Any chance of finding a replacement part?

Comment: Well, actually in my country that's very hard to do, probably I need to do it throw internet and buy it in another place

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/LTC3200ES6-5-LTSH-IC-REG-SWTCHD-CAP-5V-0-1A-SOT23-10Pcs-/291634898601?hash=item43e6cb66a9:g:g4wAAOSwcBhWZ30e maybe? Let me know if you need some tips on how to remove the old part and solder the new.